# Web GUI for editing INI files

Tags: apache, user-interface, unix, configuration

I am looking for a Unix based application or framework that would allow me to view/edit ini files on a remote system in a Html GUI via Apache (or similar).

Searching for ini/config/GUI solutions via search engines returns a lot a false positives.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on serverfault/superuser? Just suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

- Webmin supports all manor of configuration files. It has it's own (Perl) API and Web server.
- Python has the ConfigParser (or configparser in 3.0) that is geared towards INI style configuration files. You will need to use it with some communication framework like twistedn